# Any method to generate a small thumbnail for a 3d model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

To get this out of the way: I have little to no experience dealing with 3D aspects of web development. It's also worth noting that I'm relatively inexperienced with Ruby/Ruby on Rails. In my Ruby on Rails app, I want to add the ability for an administrator to upload a 3D Model to the site for others to view; For the most part, I've got this mostly covered, I just need to generate a thumbnail for the uploaded 3D model (Either an FBX or OBJ file to be specific) before the uploading process finishes. I'm currently using carrierwave to handle the uploading process.

*My controller function where I'm uploading the file:*

```
def createItem

    @newItem = Item.new(params.permit(:title, :description, :price, :stock, :categoryId))

    if (!params[:modelPath])

        render :json => {"status": false, "message": "You need to upload something!"}

        return

    end

    @itemUploader = ItemUploader.new

    @uploadedItem

    begin
        @uploadedItem = @itemUploader.store!(params[:modelPath]) # This is all im doing in order to store the item; Don't know if I need to anything more advanced than this.
    rescue => exception
        render :json => {"status": false, "message": exception}
        return;
    end

    @newFileName = @itemUploader.filename

    # Probably where I want to put the thumbnail generation method.

    if !@newItem.save

        render :json => {"status": false, "message": @newItem.errors.objects.first.full_message}

        return

    end

    if (params[:isLimited] == "on")

        @newItem.limited = true
        @newItem.save

    end

    @newItem.modelPath = @itemUploader
    @newItem.save

    render :json => {"status": "good", "item": @newItem}

  end
```

So, as you can see, I'm just using the store function in order to place the 3D model into a temp folder; Is there a way for carrierwave to generate a small PNG image of the 3D model? Is it even possible for this to happen on Ruby/Ruby on Rails? I've searched this on google, and all I can see is methods for generating thumbnails for other *images*.

Is there any method I can use in order to accomplish this effect? Or am I going to have to use an outside source in order to generate thumbnails? If you need any more information for this, I'll be happy to give it! Thank you in all in advance.

Comment: To me, the object image only exists in the browser. Basically you need something like Puppeteer or maybe Selenium to open your object in a browser or headless browser and take a snapshot. But it might be tricky. I print PDF with Puppeteer but it is dealt by Grover gem. But I don't know any wrapper that allows taking snapshots of a specific div. Also it may take some time / require hardware resources. Maybe there are other options....

Comment: Here a good link : https://www.testim.io/blog/puppeteer-screenshot/ (basically, with Puppeteer, your rails app can open a browser that is not seen by the user of your website, and then do stuff on this page like printing it as PDF or taking screenshot. But then you have to know how to upload this screenshot etc... This seems like both advanced JS and Ruby)